# Can Facebook Messenger make you active by itself on and off when data is on?

Tags: facebook-messenger

Can Facebook Messenger pop you on and off as active when you leave your data on automatically? Or does someone have to actually be on it and using it to pop on as active?

Comment: If you want your question to be found by people who can answer, use the appropriate tag(s).

Comment: Also, if this is a question about a native smartphone app, it's in the wrong place. It should instead be asked at [apple.se], [android.se], or [windowsphone.se] as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Facebook Messenger and you have login into it already, whenever you will connect to internet through mobile data or wifi it will automatically show you online. It doesn't popup. When someone ping you then only it will pop up with that person name. You can logout from Messenger anytime.